# postgres: using ANY on array of timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres function where I need to check whether or not a particular value is in an array of timestamps. Here's the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_appointments(
     for_business_id INTEGER,
     range_start DATE,
     range_end   DATE,
     for_staff_id INTEGER
    )
       RETURNS SETOF appointment
       LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
       AS $function$
     DECLARE
        appointment appointment;
        recurrence  TIMESTAMP;
        appointment_length INTERVAL;
        parent_id UUID;
     BEGIN
        FOR appointment IN
            SELECT *
              FROM appointment
             WHERE business_id = for_business_id
               AND (
                       recurrence_pattern IS NOT NULL
                   OR  (
                          recurrence_pattern IS NULL
                      AND starts_at BETWEEN range_start AND range_end
                   )
               )
         LOOP
            IF appointment.recurrence_pattern IS NULL THEN
              RETURN NEXT appointment;
              CONTINUE;
            END IF;

            appointment_length := appointment.ends_at - appointment.starts_at;
            parent_id := appointment.id;

            FOR recurrence IN
                SELECT *
                  FROM generate_recurrences(
                           appointment.recurrence_pattern,
                           appointment.starts_at,
                           range_start,
                           range_end
                  )
            LOOP
                EXIT WHEN recurrence::date > range_end;
                -- THIS IS THE LINE IN QUESTION
                CONTINUE WHEN recurrence::date < range_start OR recurrence = ANY(appointment.recurrence_exceptions);
                appointment.id := uuid_generate_v5(uuid_nil(), parent_id::varchar || recurrence::varchar);
                appointment.parent_id := parent_id;
                appointment.starts_at := recurrence;
                appointment.ends_at := recurrence + appointment_length;
                appointment.recurrence_pattern := appointment.recurrence_pattern;
                appointment.recurrence_exceptions := NULL;
                appointment.is_recurrence := true;
                RETURN NEXT appointment;
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN;
     END;
    $function$;
```

You'll see that just after the second `LOOP` statement, there's a `CONTINUE` statement. I want to skip that iteration of the loop if the `recurrence` (this is a timestamp, but in `text` format) variable is either out of range OR if it's listed as part of the `appointment`'s `recurrence_exceptions` array. The `recurrence_exceptions` array contains `timestamp`s.

The idea is that if the appointment is listed as an exception, it is not returned. Unfortunately, no matter what I do, it seems that the `ANY` operator isn't working as expected. To test this, I took one of the values from the `recurrence_exception` array and changed the `CONTINUE` statement to:

`CONTINUE WHEN recurrence::date < range_start OR recurrence = '2016-09-20 18:07:26';`

This did not return that recurrence as expected.

Am I using this properly?

Thank you!

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, both `recurrence` and `recurrence_exceptions` are stored as text. So are they stored using the same format?

Comment: `recurrence` is `text` and `recurrence_exceptions` is a `timestamp[]` array. However, I tried returning `recurrence` as `timestamp` as well with no luck.

Comment: You have to give us a minimal and complete example. Try to simplify the schema as much as possible and remove lines from the above function that are not related to your problem. Then post those here, along with some insert statements for sample data.

Comment: @redneb appreciate your help. Turns out this was a bad logic issue on my part -- nothing to do with `ANY`. Debugging these things is really difficult compared to applications! The tooling just doesn't seem to be there. Any suggestions?

Comment: So I'm confused, do you still have a problem?

Comment: No longer any issue. Thanks again!